# Vim keybinding case-insensitive

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to have a key bindings on `<C-l>` and on `<C-L>`. But it seems that Vim is case-insensitive regarding this.

For example, if I have a Vim script like this:

```
imap <C-l> <C-W>l
imap <C-L> <Plug>(copilot-accept-word)
```

And I use `<C-l>` I always use the copilot-accept-word command instead of switching to the left window.

Is there a way to make Vim case sensitive?

Comment: The first mapping doesn’t switch windows, given that it’s an insert-mode mapping

Comment: It is probably not the problem but the correct mapping is indeed: `imap <C-l> <C-o><C-w>l`

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by `<C-L>` you mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>`l` I would do:

```
imap <C-S-l> <Plug>(copilot-accept-word)
```

Or even:

```
inoremap <C-S-l> <Plug>(copilot-accept-word)
```

As @romainl says this may only work if the underlying console sent two differents codes to Vim for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>`l` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`l`.

But it should at least work on gVim.

Comment: This may not work in every context. Won't work in most terminal emulators.

Comment: I have made some test on some consoles Windows + cmd, Linux + Kitty, Ubuntu + Terminal and it seems that the `<C-S-l>` is not very well supported :-|

Comment: Sorry, that does not work for me. But I find it a bit strange that this is not supported. Why is this the case?

Comment: Vim relies on what is sent to it by the console and tries to interpret it. If the same codes are sent Vim is screwed. In GUI version Vim has full access to the keyboard and can interpret it correctly.